# How do I show that $\sin(x^2+3x+2)$ is not periodic?

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

I know that if $g(x)$ is periodic then $f(g(x))$ is periodic.

This is a sufficient condition but not necessary as $\sin(x)=f(g(x))$ is periodic where $g(x)=x$(non periodic) and $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Can the above condition be made into a necessary and sufficient condition (assuming that $g(x)$ is not the identity function) or is there a better way to find the solution?

This is from a previous year college entrance exam. Any short trick rather to check for the periodicity of $f(g(x))$ when $g(x)$ is a complicated function  would be helpful.

Comment: There needs to be a regular separation $g(x)-g(y)$. I think, if $f$ is periodic but $g$ is not, $g$ be affine: $x\mapsto mx+c$

Comment: I don't think this like of reasoning will help you. A different approach would be to assume it is periodic with a period $T$ and find an $x$ such that $f(x)\neq f(x+T)$.

Comment: But, $f,g$ can both not be periodic while $f(g)$ is periodic. Consider $f(x)=\sin(x^3),g(x)=x^{1/3}$.

Comment: @FShrike I couldn't understand your first comment

Comment: How do I proceed then?

Comment: Hint: how does its derivative behave?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose it is periodic with period $2\pi T$ for some $T>0$.  This means that for all $x$, $\sin(x^2+3x+2)=\sin((x+2\pi T)^2+3(x+2\pi T)+2)$.  Expanding the RHS gives $\sin(x^2+3x+2)=\sin(x^2+4\pi Tx+4\pi^2T^2+3x+6\pi T+2)$.

If $\sin(u)=\sin(v)$, then either $u=v-2\pi n$ or $u=\pi-v+2\pi n$ for some constant integer $n$.  We will consider each of these cases:

1. Suppose $x^2+3x+2=x^2+4\pi Tx+4\pi^2T^2+3x+6\pi T+2 - 2\pi n$.  Then:
   $$2\pi n=4\pi Tx+4\pi^2T^2+6\pi T$$
   $$n=Tx+\pi T+3T$$
   $n$ is a constant, so $\frac\partial{\partial x}(Tx+\pi T+3T)=0$ (as is the case for all higher derivatives).  Calculating the derivative shows that $T=0$, but we previously defined that $T>0$, a contradiction.
2. Suppose $x^2+3x+2=\pi-x^2-4\pi Tx-4\pi^2T^2-3x-6\pi T-2 + 2\pi n$.  Then:
   $$2x^2+6x+4-\pi+4\pi Tx+4\pi^2T^2+6\pi T = 2\pi n$$
   $$n=\frac 1\pi x^2+\frac3\pi x+\frac 2\pi-\frac 12+2 Tx+2\pi T^2+3T$$
   As in the previous case, $n$ is constant, so $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(\frac 1\pi x^2+\frac3\pi x+\frac 2\pi-\frac 12+2 Tx+2\pi T^2+3T)=0$.  Calculating this derivative gives the false statement $\frac 2\pi=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

A continuous periodic function [is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775045/how-do-i-show-that-all-continuous-periodic-functions-are-bounded-and-uniform-con).

We let $f:x\mapsto x^2+3x+2$ and we note that for $n\geq 1$, there exists unique $x_n<y_n$ such that $f(x_n) = 2n\pi$ and $f(y_n) = \pi/4+2n\pi$.
By the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $\xi_n\in (x_n,y_n)$ such that
$$\frac{\sin(f(y_n))-\sin(f(x_n))}{y_n-x_n} = (2\xi_n+3)\cos(f(\xi_n))$$
Since $f$ is increasing over $[0,\infty)$, $f(x_n)\leq f(\xi_n)\leq f(y_n)$, hence $\cos(f(\xi_n))\geq 1/\sqrt 2$ and
$$0<y_n-x_n\leq \frac{1}{2\xi_n+3}.$$

As a consequence, $y_n-x_n\to_n 0$, but $\sin(f(y_n))-\sin(f(x_n)) = 1/\sqrt 2$, [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178509/characterization-of-uniform-continuity-via-sequence) $\sin\circ f$ is not uniformly continuous, hence not periodic.

Answer (score 2):

We show the following lemma first:

**Lemma.**  A continuously differentiable differentiable periodic function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has bounded derivative.

*Proof.* Suppose $f$ has period $T$. It is clear that $f'$ must also then have period $T$. By continuity, $\lvert f'\rvert$ attains a maximum on $[0,T]$, and by periodicity

$$\max_{x\in[0,T]}\lvert f'(x)\rvert =\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\lvert f'(x)\rvert.$$

Thus $f'$ is bounded. $\square$

We now move on to your function

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\sin(x^2+3x+2).$$

We can now prove that $f$ is not periodic if we can prove that $f'$ is unbounded. Now we have that

$$f'(x)=(2x+3)\cos(x^2+3x+2).$$

But notice that then, if we choose a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n\to\infty$ and $x_n^2+3x_n+2=2\pi k_n$ for some sequence of integers $\{k_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, then

$$\lvert f'(x_n)\rvert = \lvert 2x_n+3\rvert\to\infty$$

as $n\to\infty$, and so $f'$ is unbounded. It follows that $f$ is not periodic.